# Как можно в IDE Rider запустить несколько проектов одновременно без задержек?

Tags: c#, jetbrains, rider

Как можно в IDE Rider запустить несколько C# проектов одновременно без задержек?
Буду благодарен если покажите на скринах)

Comment: Новую конфигурацию запуска создайте: Жмем `Run > Edit Configurations`, далее жмем там `+` и выбираем `Compound`, в правой части добавляем все проекты, которые должны быть запущены, сохраняем, запускаем эту конфигурацию. Больше способов вряд-ли найдете.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо.